# What tells the browser to retrieve from cache/ reload a .js file? Behaviour appears to be random despite cache-control header

Tags: .net, angular, iis, browser-cache, response-headers

I managed to set a cache-control header for js files in .net 5 and I can see the response headers in the request in the browser.

To test this, I repeatedly refresh the page/ enter in the page from another location and the file seemingly reloads/ retrieves from cache *at random*. Sometimes from "memory cache" and sometimes "1.1 MB" which is the size of the file.

The response headers look like this:

```
accept-ranges: bytes
age: 63
cache-control: public, max-age=9999999
content-length: 1144984
content-type: application/javascript
date: Sat, 27 Feb 2021 16:44:36 GMT
etag: "1d70bcf6330ed98"
expires: Mon, 29 Mar 2021 16:43:33 GMT
last-modified: Thu, 25 Feb 2021 23:38:58 GMT
server: Microsoft-IIS/10.0
strict-transport-security: max-age=2592000
vary: Accept-Encoding
x-powered-by: ASP.NET
```

Am I missing something?

Answer (score 0):

As you can see from your response header, the files that can be cached are public unencrypted files, and there is no specific file validity time set, only the expiration time is 3.29.

When you visit for the first time, the js file is successfully cached locally. When you visit for the second time after a period of time, the original cache has not expired and the etag verification finds that these static files are not updated, then the browser will load the static files from the local cache.

Then you refresh the same page repeatedly in a short period of time, and these files are loaded directly from memory instead of being cached locally. According to the design logic of windows, when resources are currently in priority use, commonly used resources will be taken out of local storage and placed in memory, so that they can be obtained faster next time they are used. So unless your static resources expire, the browser will retrieve static resources from the server again.